# How to create a MONGODB query that checks if a specific field contains the value of another field in the document?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to build a complex query in mongodb with multiple nested conditions and one of the conditions needs to check if a specific field contains the value from the same document of another field.

Its very important to be built without aggregation and to be a normal query so we can integrate it in the process and combine them with other conditions;

For example the following query works correctly to check if the $brand is the direct string, but i would like to check if the $title includes the $brand field.

```php
Array
(
    [$and] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [$and] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [$and] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [brand] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [$exists] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [brand] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [$ne] =>
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [brand] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [$ne] =>
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [$expr] => Array
                                        (
                                            [$not] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [$regexMatch] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [input] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [$toString] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [0] => $title
                                                                                )

                                                                        )

                                                                    [regex] => $brand
                                                                    [options] => i
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

i tried multiple versions with or without regex but i cannot make it work

the issue is this

```php
 [1] => Array
            (
                [$expr] => Array
                    (
                        [$not] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [$regexMatch] => Array
                                            (
                                                [input] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [$toString] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => $title
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [regex] => $brand
                                                [options] => i
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

This is because i cannot manage to make a conditions/expression so that we can the documents that have a specific field that contains the value of another field.

I am using mongodb 6.0.1 and latest php driver.

Comment: What language and version (db and driver) are you using? What does it mean to '_integrate it in the process and combine them with other conditions_'? What is not working about your current attempt?

Comment: i am using mongodb version 6 and the latest php version, the issue is that i cannot create a query with a condition if a field contains the value of another field.  basically  the second condition does not work

Comment: Why can you not use aggregation...>?